# DataNucleus add existing multiple foreign keys to Object

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

Using JDO and DataNucleus If i have a `@PersistenceCapable` class like

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Topic  {

            @PrimaryKey
            @Unique
            @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.UUIDHEX)
            private String id;
    }
```

and another

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Subscription  {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Unique
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.UUIDHEX)
    private String id;

    @Persistent
    @Join(column="SUBSCRIBE_ID_OID")
    @Element(column="TOPIC_ID_EID")
    private List<Topic> topics;

}
```

In my client code, I download a list of topics, each with an ID and add those topics to a list in a new Subscription

A JSON post body may look like this:

```
{
    "topics": [{

        "id": "402881115c63f3da015c63f3daa40000",

    }, {

        "id": "402881115c63f3da015c63f3daca0001",

    }, {

        "id": "402881115c63f3da015c63f3dade0002",

    }]
}
```

I now want to persist my new Subscription thusly:

```
 public void addEntity(Subscription s) {
        PersistenceManager pm = persistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager();

        try{
            pm.makePersistent(s);

        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }
```

What i expect, is a 1-N relationship in the Join table of the new Subscription and the existing Topics. When I get is three new Topics with new IDs inserted into the Topic table with a 1-N relationship to the new records.

It makes sense to me that DN is taking my persitence of the new Subscription and treating the list like new data, i'm trying to figure out how to do this correctly so the list of topics are the original ids.

Comment: No idea what that post is trying to say. You have a 1-N join table relation, so have tables BAR, BAR_FOOS and FOO. And ? You post no persistence code for creating objects and join table entries. If you mean you already have some Foo objects then RETRIEVE those objects and add them to the Bar

Comment: thanks - i added some edits for clarification, it sounds like i need to rebuild my list with attached objects - i'm sure i'll figure this out, i appreciate the response

Comment: when you receive your JSON response, for each topic, check for their existence using `pm.getObjectById`? and if not present then create a new one (rather than just creating a new one)

Comment: yes, before calling  pm.makePersistent(s); I iterate through the topics, call get object by id and replace the detached Subscription with the response, then everything works perfectly.  Feel free to post this as the answer and I'll mark it as such.  Thanks Neil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON response needs to take into account whether objects actually exist in the datastore. So if you iterate through your `Topic` objects and call `pm.getObjectById` to provide this check, then, if an object is returned then you can use this attached `Topic` instead of the detached one you had originally in the `Subscription` List.

Thereafter calling `pm.makePersistent` will find the attached objects and just set the join table entries accordingly (with FK to existent rows in the TOPIC table), without creating new element objects